In Karate 1.0, the karate property set in karate-config.js file is coming as null when fetched in a Java File
In Karate 1.0,karate-config.js has below property set.
karate.properties['Serviceurl'] = config.InfoUrl;
Now the value of Serviceurl is fetched in a Java file as below. But it is returning null.
String Serviceurl = System.getProperty("Serviceurl");
I was expecting the property value set in karate to be available in Java file.

just so you know karate 1.0 is a very old version and you won't get any help for that

FYI, I have tested the same with Karate 1.3.0 that supports Java 8. The issue still exist.

lets hope someone here can help you, if you are really serious about getting help, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Created a new ticket for testing in Karate 1.2.0.RC1 version https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2552
